# Linq query result into two objects

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I currently have the following linq which runs and gets two strongly typed objects (DAL.Driver and DAL.Licence).  However I want to cast the result out in to the a single DriverODSJoined object that contains a BLL.Driver and BLL.Licence object.

```
public class DriverODSJoined
{
    public BLL.Driver driver { get; set; }
    public BLL.Licence licence { get; set; }

    public static void GetData()
    {
        DAL.DriverDataContext dataContext = new DAL.DriverDataContext();

        var query = (from d in dataContext.drivers
                     join c in dataContext.licences on d.licence_id equals c.id into t1
                     from t2 in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { Driver = d, Licence = t2 });
    }
}
```

For linked queries in to one class object i would do this:

```
query.Select(a => new BLL.Driver.Driver()
        {
            id = a.Driver.id
            etc
        }).ToList();
```

So to populate a list of DriverODSJoined I thought I would do something like this:

```
  query.Select(a => new BLL.Driver.DriverODSJoined()
        {
            driver.id = a.Driver.id,
            licence.id = t2.id
        }).ToList();
```

However it doesn't work.  How can I do this to end up with a List each of which contains an instance of a BLL.Driver and BLL.Licence object?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: I was being stupid, all I needed to do was: List<DriverODSJoined> list = query.Select(a => new DriverODSJoined()
                {
                    driver = new Driver()
                    {
                        address1 = a.driver.address1
                    },
                    
                    check = new BLL.DVLA.Licence()
                    {
                       id = a.licence.id
                    }
                    
                }
                ).ToList();

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and accept it. This will help other people with similar problems

Comment: I tried to but I have to wait 7 hours from posting so will have to come back to it.  Wanted to at least put a comment so nobody wasted their time answering it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out shortly afterwards and of course I had to instantiate each object within the containing object before assigning values to their member variables.  So here is the example:

```
List<DriverODSJoined> list = query.Select(a => new DriverODSJoined()
{ 
    driver = new Driver()
    { 
        address1 = a.driver.address1
    },
    check = new BLL.DVLA.Licence()
    {
        id = a.licence.id 
    } 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Also as an update I found that when the licence from the left join was null I had to do: `check = a.licence = null ? new BLL.DVLA.Licence() : new BLL.DVLA.Licence() { id = a.licence.id }` as the process was falling over as member variable on the licence object like id were a non nullable int